# assistance with binary reverse order printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

This is code I have found for converting Decimal to Binary, It outputs fine, but It says on the page I got it from it says prints the binary number in reverse order.. I can't see it and I'm wondering if someone could explain this to me :)

```
def convertToBinary(n):
   """Function to print binary number
   for the input decimal using recursion"""
   if n > 1:
       convertToBinary(n//2)
   print(n % 2,end = '')

# decimal number
dec = 34

convertToBinary(dec)
```

Comment: "prints the binary number in reverse order" But it doesn't

Comment: It's printing in correct order. Not in reverse.

Comment: Right, so it loops through, floor division of n, and then prints the remainder of n%2 from left to right? correct? I wonder why it says it prints in reverse order...